# How to split a string into multiple lines using regex before the pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with the swift data in the below format that needs to be split into multiple lines using regular expression in python.
Original file:

```
ID        Information

1         :20:Test1  :25:test2:28C:test3
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  Information

1     :20:Test1  
1     :25:test2  
1     :28C:test3
```

Using Notepad++ I am able to break the 'Information'column into multiple lines using

**Find:**  `^:[0-9]{2}:|\s:[0-9]{2}:|\s:[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}:`

**Replace :** `\n$0`

Need to replicate the same using python. So far i tried the below code but the result does not contain the pattern. It is splitting after the pattern match:

```
import re

s = ':20:Test1  :25:test2:28C:test3'

l = re.compile('^:[0-9]{2}:|\s:[0-9]{2}:|\s:[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}:').split(s)
```

**Result:** `['', 'Test1 ', 'test2 ', 'test3']`

The result should also contain the regex pattern while splitting the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
text = """ID        Information

1         :20:Test1  :25:test2:28C:test3"""

valid_line_rx = r'^(\d+\s*)(:\d{2}[A-Za-z]?:.*)'
print( re.sub(valid_line_rx, lambda m:
  "\n".join(["{}{}".format(m.group(1),x) for x in re.split(r'(?!^)(?=:\d{2}[A-Za-z]?:)', m.group(2))]),
  text, 
  flags=re.M)
)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t8ArdO), output:

```
ID        Information

1         :20:Test1  
1         :25:test2
1         :28C:test3
```

The [`^(\d+\s*)(:\d{2}[A-Za-z]?:.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/kTizS8/1/) regex matches

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M` flag)
- `(\d+\s*)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then 0 or more whitespaces
- `(:\d{2}[A-Za-z]?:.*)` - Group 2: `:`, two digits, an optional letter and a a `:` and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The `(?!^)(?=:\d{2}[A-Za-z]?:)` regex matches a location that is not the start of string and is immediately followed with `:`, 2 digits, an optional letter and a `:`, and this pattern is used to split the Group 2 value of the above regex match.

Comment: This was very helpful. Appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern:

```
import re

s = ':20:Test1  :25:test2:28C:test3'

p = re.compile('(:[0-9A-z]{1,3}:)([0-9A-z]+)')

print(p.findall(s))
#[(':20:', 'Test1'), (':25:', 'test2'), (':28C:', 'test3')]
```

Comment: Just to give back ground the data is a swift format data containing tags and corresponding value and so value 'Test1'  can be a combination of numbers, alphabets, special characters including colons(:). The ':20:' can have two numeric digit  or two numeric followed by an alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have multiple types of output, it may be easier to use a little logic with a regex:

```
s='''\
ID        Information

1         :20:Test1  :25:test2:28C:test3'''
    

import re 

for line in s.splitlines():
    if m:=re.search(r'^(\d+)([ \t]+)(:.*)',line):
        data=re.findall(r'(:[^:]+:[^:]+(?=:|$))', m.group(3))
        for e in data:
            print(m.group(1)+m.group(2)+e.rstrip())
    else:
        print(line)
```

Prints:

```
ID        Information

1         :20:Test1
1         :25:test2
1         :28C:test3
```

As written, that is Python 3.8+ only. If you want on an earlier Python 3.X:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    m=re.search(r'^(\d+)([ \t]+)(:.*)',line)
    if m:
      ...
```

Comment: Just to give back ground the data is a swift format data containing tags and corresponding value and so value 'Test1' can be a combination of numbers, alphabets, special characters including colons(:). The ':20:' can have two numeric digit or two numeric followed by an alphabet.

Comment: If `:` is not an acceptable delimiter, please clarify what is an acceptable delimiter. If there are no delimiters, likely it is a fixed width format. If it is not fixed width and has no delimiters -- good luck.